# How to read added record on list add on event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

i have a list/Event by following code

```
     class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {

        public event EventHandler OnAdd;

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (null != OnAdd)
            {
                OnAdd(this, null);
            }
            base.Add(item);
        }

    }

    MyList<connectedUser> myListUsers = new MyList<connectedUser>();
    myListUsers.OnAdd += new EventHandler (myListUsers_OnAdd );

    private void myListUsers_OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
public class connectedUser
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string marketID { get; set; }
}
```

In my on OnAdd event (myListUsers_OnAdd), i want my inserted object as Parameter in other word how i can read that inserted object inside event

Answer (score 2):

You should use ObservableCollection, this has already an event that gets called when objects are added or removed.

**Example:**

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
collection.CollectionChanged += CollectionOnCollectionChanged;
```

and your method looks like this:

```
private static void CollectionOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) {
    //notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems <= this are the items that got added
    //notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.OldItems <= this are the items that got removed
}
```

Comment: I add an example.

Comment: where you add an example  ?

Comment: OK got it ..sorry

Comment: You can just loop throught the items, if none was added or removed the list should be empty.